# About Linux PID0 Idle task per cpu core

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cpu, power-management, android-kernel

I am working on CPU-IDLE in Linux. I have the question who spawns idle tasks per CPU core i.e. if there are 4 arm CPU cores, who spawns the per CPU idle task? Where the code for the same is located for creating idle tasks? I understand that start_kernel in init/main.c is run by init process.

Can someone please point out the location of the code where the idle tasks are created per CPU core for CPU idle?

Regards,
Snu

Answer (score 2):

Using the 5.3 kernel as a reference:

- `start_kernel()` in "init/main.c" calls `arch_call_rest_init()`.
- `arch_call_rest_init()` in "init/main.c" calls `rest_init()`.
- `rest_init()` in "init/main.c" calls `kernel_thread()` to create the init process with `kernel_init` as the thread function.
- `kernel_init()` in "init/main.c" calls `kernel_init_freeable()`.
- `kernel_init_freeable()` in "init/main.c" calls `smp_init()`.
- `smp_init()` in "kernel/smp.c" calls `idle_threads_init()`.
- `idle_threads_init()` in "kernel/smpboot.c" calls `idle_init(cpu)` for each CPU apart from the boot CPU.
- `idle_cpu(cpu)` in "kernel/smpboot.c" calls `fork_idle(cpu)`.
- `fork_idle(cpu)` in "kernel/fork.c" clones the init process thread and calls `init_idle(task, cpu)`.
- `init_idle(task, cpu)` in "kernel/sched/core.c" sets up the idle thread for the CPU.